# in which repository can i find python-imobiledevice and other missing related packages

Tags: python, rhythmbox

My goal is to be able to move music from the computer to my iPod. Rhythmbox is able to see the iPod and play music from it. I'm trying to install imobiledevice, but I cannot do it because some packages can't be located. I guess I should find them in a repository, but after some research on internet I could not find anything. The missing packages are python-imobiledevice, libimobiledevice4, libplist2. As you can see in the screenshot, I also have a message that package python-plist has no candidate.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may be following an outdated tutorial. The package `python-imobiledevice` has been replaced by `python3-imobiledevice` which uses Python 3 (rather than Python 2.

Installing that package instead may or may not work, depending on whether the guide takes into account the changes made to migrate from Python 2 to Python 3.